# vue use web3.js Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in ./node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (246:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|         }
|         return signed({
|             ...tx,
|             ...((isNot(tx.common) || isNot(tx.common.customChain.chainId)) ? { chainId: txchainId } : {}),
|             nonce: txnonce,

@ ./node_modules/web3-eth/lib/index.js 33:15-43
@ ./node_modules/w`enter code here`eb3/lib/index.js
@ ./src/main.js
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please read [ask].

Comment: By the way, you probably want to give [this package](https://github.com/morrislaptop/vue-web3) a try.